# Cassandra client is not showing changes made through json2sstable

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have converted sstable to Json file using Cassandra sstable2json utility and then modified some row values, now i invoked the utility json2sstable.The Utlity json2sstable executed successfully using following command.

command:

```
bin/json2sstable -s -K UserDemo -c Users Users.json /opt/dse-2.1/dse-data/UserDemo/Users-hd-1-Data.db
```

I tried to see the changes are reflected or not using cassandra client. Noticed that changes are not reflected what i did using json2sstable utility.

and I tried to refresh the CF Users using nodetool but no changes noticed.

Please advice on what could be the reason for not reflecting in the cassandra.

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON import/export is really intended for debugging; if you are trying to do some kind of bulk load, look at cqlsh `COPY FROM` (starting in 1.1.2) or the sstableloader tool.

That said, if you are manually injecting new sstables, you need to invoke the ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables method.  This is not exposed over nodetool.  (Remember: intended for debugging.)  You'd need to invoke it with jvisualvm or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I understood these utilities for debuging and I am not trying for bulk load or loading new sstable. Trying to update the existing a sstable using this utlity and validate the same through the client. Can be achived using this utility?